# Select number of rows in all tables in the database

Tags: mysql

I wonder if this is possible with straight SQL on MySQL. I need to do SELECT COUNT(*) FROM on each table in the database and output results in one result set.

Is it possible to do with just SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is in fact. You have to use INFORMATION_SCHEMA. In INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables there's a column TABLE_ROWS.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html

Comment: This information is reliable only for some engines. For others, the only way to get the real number of rows is to run `SELECT COUNT(*)`. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html

Comment: Extended answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24707814/mysql-summarize-all-table-row-counts-in-a-single-query

Answer (score 0):

if one SQL counts as a stored proc, then yes!

.. you could do with a cursor and dynamic sql.

```
exec("select count(*) from " + @tableName)
```

....type thing!

I'm sure that mysql probably has a built in SQL or SP that will do this for you, I'm afraid I don't know what it is though.

Comment: That's SQL Server dynamic SQL syntax - you need to change it to use MySQL's Prepared Statement syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html